# What does the keyword "device" mean in the Metal Shading Language

Tags: ios, metal

What does the keyword "device" mean in the Metal Shading Language?
As in:

```
kernel void add_alps_2d_kernel(const device int *vector1 [[buffer(1)]],
                           device int vector2 [[buffer(2)]],
                           uint id [[ thread_position_in_grid ]]) {

}
```

Answer (score 7):

According to the [language spec doc](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf)

> Arguments to Metal graphics and kernel functions declared in a program
>   that are pointers must be declared with the Metal device, threadgroup,
>   threadgroup_imageblock, or constant address space attribute.

Furthermore:

> The device address space name refers to buffer memory objects
>   allocated from the device memory pool that are both readable and
>   writeable.

So its a memory specification that indicates where the pointer is located. Note that the use of `const` preceding the address space attribute indicates that it is read only. You can additionally find more information in [Working with memory in Metal](http://metalkit.org/2017/04/30/working-with-memory-in-metal.html)

Comment: On iOS the GPU memory and the CPU memory are shared.  What does adding the word device actually mean?  Are there any situations where it is not necessary?

Comment: The word device is just a type of "address space attribute". Per the spec some sort of address space attribute is always needed for pointers when passed as an arg.